# Gradle error: No such property: targetCompatibility

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I've got that error:

> Error:No such property: targetCompatibility for class: org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject_Decorated

When trying to include subproject gdx-facebook to my Android Studio project.
I added it by "Import existing project" in Project structure options.

settings.gradle:

```
include 'desktop', 'html', 'core', 'android', ':gdx-facebook-android', ':gdx-facebook-core', ':gdx-facebook-desktop'
project(':gdx-facebook-android').projectDir = new File('libs/gdx-facebook/gdx-facebook-android')
project(':gdx-facebook-core').projectDir = new File('libs/gdx-facebook/gdx-facebook-core')
project(':gdx-facebook-desktop').projectDir = new File('libs/gdx-facebook/gdx-facebook-desktop')
```